# Android TV not correctly identified by Windows 10 for wireless display

Tags: windows-10, android, tv

On windows, if I go to Settings > Display > Connect to a wireless display, my TV is not listed there. But, if I go to Settings > Devices, it is listed under "Other devices". Same situation with my soundbar as well. Is this because Windows has identified the device type incorrectly? How can this be fixed?

I cannot find any options or settings for this device. It is also not under Device manager.

In contrast, I can connect from my Android phone to the TV just at the click of a button "Wireless display" and it works. Casting through Google Chrome also works from Windows to TV (This has high lag though).

Comment: It detected the device properly. If your display is not listed, in the list of devices supported for wireless display, that tells me your device does not actually support the requirements for wireless display.  Your Android phone, is not running Windows, so it's not a relevant test case.

Answer (score 0):

Miracast/Chromecast is natively available on a TV when the right
adapter is integrated into the TV electronics. Even if a TV has it built-in, it might not support the Windows 10 variety of
the Wireless display protocol.

What you should do:

- Search in your TV settings for any mention of Miracast or
  Chromecast that can be enabled.
- Search in your TV Google Play Store a Miracast or Chromecast
  app. If found, install it, start it, fix its settings if required,
  then try casting with the app still open.
- At worst, you could get a more recent Chromecast device to connect
  to the TV.

Comment: I very much doubt your assertions about Miracast needing an app and/or being no longer supported on Android. Please provide a direct link to this app.

Comment: Miracast driver support was dropped by Nvidia and AMD a half decade ago (2015).  What is more likely is that the Windows machine simply does not support Miracast ( also known as Wi-Fi Direct).  While the Android device, is able to connect to an Android TV, likely by using Chromecast.  [Android dropped Miracast support back in 2015.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast). The current status of Miracast is extremely difficult to determine, all evidence indicates is that support for it was dropped in Windows 10 (lack of driver support) and in Android, by Microsoft document still refers to it.

Comment: Please stop. Windows 10 has built-in support for Miracast so display drivers don't have to implement it. Miracast is also known as Wireless Display. It is certainly built on Wi-Fi Direct but is not the same. What Android mobile devices support is also not entirely relevant here.

Comment: I stand corrected and fixed my answer.